# Variable in derived class may have not been initialized (using constructors)

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, constructor, multiple-inheritance

I am new to Java Programming and i am trying to experiment with inheritance and constructors.

My parent class:

```
class user{

    private String name;
    private float balance;
    private int accno;
    private int passw;

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    //getters and setters for the remaining variables.
}
```

My derived class:

```
class userFunct extends user
{

    userFunct(int accno,String name,int passw,float bal){                   //parametrized constructor

        super.setPassw(passw);
        super.setName(name);
        super.setAccno(accno);
        super.setBalance(bal);
    }
```

In my main program, i do this:

```
public static void main()
{
    userFunct obj=new userFunct(accno,name,passw,bal);  //Creating an object userFunct
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I get an error saying

> variable accno may not have been initialized

Now since this had lots of lines i wrote a smaller piece of code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class a{
    public int x;

}

class b extends a{
    /*static*/ void pri(a obj)
    {
        System.out.println("Class b"+obj.x);
    }
    b(int num)
    {
        super.x=num;
    }
}


public class Main
{
    int num=9;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        b objb=new b(9);
        objb.pri(objb);
    }
}
```

And this works fine, with proper outputs. 
I cannot spot the mistake when i compare the two codes.

I don't know if this is some silly mistake on my side or if there is some underlying concept that i have failed to understand. Either ways, I would like to know what is happening here

Comment: You never set the value of `accno` in the `main` method of your first example.

Comment: Is `userFunct obj=new userFunct(accno,name,passw,bal);` the literal first line of your main method? In that case, the `accno` you refer to there has not been initialized (or any of the other variables you use, for  that matter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between two code you shared in **user class** you declared all variable as **private** and **not initialised**. In your class **a** you declared variable as public.

So assign a initial value to all variable an enjoy

```
class user {
String name = "";
float balance = 0.0f;
int accno = 0;
int passw = 0;

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public float getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(float balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}

public int getAccno() {
    return accno;
}

public void setAccno(int accno) {
    this.accno = accno;
}

public int getPassw() {
    return passw;
}

public void setPassw(int passw) {
    this.passw = passw;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'd go with the point I think is much more important than the question being asked: please be very serious about **naming conventions** in your code from the very beginning of your learning journey. You may think that *ahh.. it's not important now.. I'm interested in something else*.. but please always name your variables/classes/methods according to the naming conventions and good practices, otherwise you'll get used to this quite easily.. and even after working in Java industry for around decade, I think the **proper naming** is still one of the most important thing, even senior engineers lack as a behavioral pattern. Keep your code clean from the very beginning.

I have rewritten your first question in an `IntelliJ` with making sure, that I implement respective getters/setters and I initialize all the variables I'm passing to the `userFunct` constructor before I pass them.

Something like

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int accno=1;
        String name="test";
        int passw=1234;
        float bal=2f;
        userFunct obj=new userFunct(accno,name,passw,bal);
    }
```

..and I don't get any Compile Time warnings or errors.

Make sure you initialize whatever you pass into constructor of `userFunct`, and that you have properly written your setters and getters.